# Send a polymorphic object over serial

Tags: serial, programming, c++, pointer

I am sending a polymorphic object over serial between two Arduinos. The transmission should be fine, indeed if on the receiver side I `static_cast` the pointer to the `Derived` class it works properly. On the other hand if I try to call virtual functions on the `Base` pointer, Arduino resets. What is causing this behaviour?

Some samples of the code follows.

Sender:

```
RS485_Serial bus;
void loop ()
{
  Random r(1); //targeting device 1 in the bus
  if (r.request(bus)) { blink(r.val); } //make a request for a random number
                                        //blink the led the given number of times

  delay(1000);
}
```

Receiver:

```
RS485_Serial bus;
bus.set_address(1);
void loop ()
{
  listen(bus);
}
```

Selected common parts:

```
struct Action {
  byte target_address;

  Action(byte addr): target_address(addr) {}
  virtual ~Action() {}

  virtual size_t size() const { return sizeof(*this); }
  virtual int  vrequest(RS485_Serial &) = 0;
  virtual void vrespond(RS485_Serial &) = 0;

  int request(RS485_Serial & bus) {
    bus.write(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(this), size());
    return vrequest(bus);
  }
  void respond(RS485_Serial & bus) {
    vrespond(bus); // <--- This virtual call makes the sender reset
  }
};

struct Random: Action {
  size_t size() const override { return sizeof(*this); }
  int val;
  Random(byte address): Action(address) {}

  int vrequest(RS485_Serial & bus) override {
    return bus.read(val);
  }
  void vrespond(RS485_Serial & bus) override {
    bus.write(static_cast<decltype(val)>(random(2,5)));
  }
};

void listen(RS485_Serial & bus) {
  byte * data = nullptr;
  byte length = 0;
  if ( bus.read(data, length) ){
    Action & a = *(reinterpret_cast<Action*>(data));
    if (a.size() == length) blink(3);
    if (a.target_address == bus.address) {
      a.respond(bus);
      //static_cast<Random*>(&a)->vrespond(); works but it has no point
    }
  }
}
```

My doubt is that if the vtable is stored in different positions, than the vtable pointer in the object obtained by the receiver will be off, causing the crash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is general C++ programming, not specific to Arduino (other that the incidental use of a serial link).

Comment: Please edit your question to include complete, minimal sketches that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @LookAlterno could this be moved to stackexchange?

Comment: You are accessing a Null pointer and getting a segmentation fault.  Suggest you test you code under Visual Studio or Linux equivalent and see where the debugger flags the fault.

Comment: @LookAlterno - I agree and disagree, because there is some element of hardware (serial) that could be causing the issues, most likely because the data is being sent as binary and read as text or similar.

Comment: I think you're going to have to show your code for both sender and receiver for us to have any clue what is or might be going on.

Comment: `Action::vrespond` is PV and can't be called. Only `Random::vrespond` can be called.

Comment: @Majenko it is supposed to be like that: the call should be resolved to `Random::vrespond`. If it was like you said it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: How can it be resolved to `Random::vrespond` if it's cast to Action?

Comment: If you have super-class `A` that is the parent of both classes `X` and `Y`, and `foo` is a PV interface in `A` and implemented in both `X` and `Y`, and you cast an object to `A`, how does it know where `foo` is implemented? It could be in either `X` or `Y`. It can't know that kind of thing. You have to cast it to the right class to access the functions in that class.

Comment: @Majenko The point of polymorphic pointers is to avoid that cast by means of virtual functions. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5ffb8ecab28708a

Comment: @Majenko The compiler creates some machinery for that to work (vpointer and vtable) which I suspect is not created on the receiver or at least it doesn't match with the sender. I may have to write them myself to ensure that they match on both sides.

Comment: I do not agree that this question would suit StackOverflow better, this is quite Arduino specific for multitude of reasons for ex. Harvard architecture and serial implementation, just to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

I think http://stackoverflow.com is the correct forum for your question. Your problem is how to serialize/deserialize correctly an object in C++.

An easy way to do it is simply send the values (not the object) and recreate the object at the other side. So, now your problem is reduced to send and receive a bunch of int's, float's, string's, whatever.

Why you want/need to do that?

Comment: The object is serialised fine, but I think that there might be inconsistencies between the vtables allocated on the two boards. The aim is to have an arduino launching functions on another one which I planned to do encapsulating lambdas inside polymorphic objects. I may just fall back to a plain old switch statement.

Comment: I looks like you want to send some code (as opposed some data) to be executed at the other Arduino. Arduino uses Harvard architecture, so you can't put code in RAM and execute it. I'm curious about what are you trying to do.

Comment: Also take in mind sometimes on different CPUs int values from 2 to 4 bytes can be stored differently (it's called little/big endian).

Comment: @DarioP the point is that you can't serialize the methods of an object between machines of this type; you can only serialize the data which uniquely specifies of object of the class.  You need to have a compatible class on the receiving side, and inflate an instance of it with a constructor taking the serialized data.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect then that the object contains a pointer to the code for `vrespond`, which is at a specific (and differing from program to program) location in flash memory. An object in C++ isn't a single atomic item, it is a collection of data and pointers to functions. On a Harvard architecture system the data is in RAM and the code is in Flash (you cannot typically execute code from RAM). The compiler chooses where to place the code in Flash when it compiles (well, the linker does). That won't be the same address in different programs. All you are doing is sending over the addresses in flash that the code resides at - and those addresses are incorrect. By specifically casting it to a type that has code available you are also telling it where that code resides. Without that manual cast you are having to rely on the (incorrect) function pointers.

It is a bad idea to transfer objects like that from one system to another. It is better to transfer just the data and feed that data into an existing object created on the receiver. How you send and receive that data and feed it into the object is up to you.